# How to make gradle override a resource in a library project

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-resources, android-flavors

Currently I got a project called 'Common', and a application called 'Setup' which depends on 'Common'.

In 'Common', there is a 'color.xml' which is an Android resource file.

What I want is depending on build type override some values in 'color.xml'.

I've tried to set `res.srcDirs = ['path/for/override/resources']` , but seems it does not work.

Anyone can give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a resource in `colors.xml` with the same name and put into your build type's directory: `yourbuildtype/res/colors.xml`. This will override the value of the resource specified in library.

Comment: Flavor works, but do know how to implement this just use build type?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. You want to override that value only for particular build type?

Comment: Yes, say there's a build type named "myTest", if use that build type, than the "color.xml" in "path/for/override/resources" will override the default "color.xml"

Comment: Override that value in `myTest/res/colors.xml`.